# Clear notifications using OneSignal and Ionic on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, notifications, onesignal

In my app, users can create posts that can generate alerts to other users based on the content. The server receives the new post and sends notifications using the OneSignal API. No problems there, all notifications arrive to all intended users.

When the users receive the notification and they click on the newly arrived notification, the app opens and the notification dissappears. Excelent.

However, when a user gets the notification but enters the app without clicking on the notification, I also want the notifications gone.

How can I clear all my app notifications? I am using [OneSignal-Cordova-SDK](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK)
 .

Thank you

Comment: "The OneSignal SDK automatically sets the badge count on your app to the number of notifications that are currently in the notification shade."
The problem is that I need to set the badge count to 0 when the user enters a specific section, not my app. How can I achieve this?
P.D. why the downvote? At least leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the solution myself. I had to manually add code to the OneSignal.js included in the plugin to access the clearOneSignalNotifications() function.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding this to a page that loads when the app resumes:

```
window["plugins"].OneSignal.clearOneSignalNotifications();
```

And in index.html  tag:

```
 <!-- ONESIGNAL WEB PUSH -->
  <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async></script>
  <script>
    var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  </script>
```